# Text game: How to store commands in a class

Tags: python

I am making a text game (various smaller text games until I am absolutely comfortable.), and there will be a lot of commands. So for example:

If the player is in the "Credits" screen. And if there is one central command, for example, "help". How would I have the command "help" list all of the available commands?

What I am asking is, how would I store all of the custom commands in a class, then call them? Or is it even possible?

Comment: You need to post some code and explain what you've tried that hasn't worked.

Answer (score 2):

The [module cmd](http://doughellmann.com/2008/05/pymotw-cmd.html) is often overlooked but sounds like just what you might be needing. As they say, the [batteries *are* included](http://www.python.org/about/).

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, please use the search function, or at least Google. Do not expect help if you haven't demonstrated you've done your fair share of researching.

That said, here's an example to get you started. You might write a function to accept input from the keyboard and use conditional statements to output the correct information:

```
class MyClass():

    def menu(self):
        strcmd = raw_input('Enter your input:')
        if strcmd == "help":
            self.help_func()
        elif strcmd == "exit":
            sys.exit(0);
        else:
            print("Unknown command")

    def help_func(self):
        print("Type 'help' for help.")
        print("Type 'exit' to quit the application.")

    # ...
```

If you want to get fancy, you can store function pointers in a dictionary and avoid conditionals altogether:

```
class MyClass():

    def __init__(self):
        self.cmds = {"help": help_func, "info": info_func}

    def menu(self):
        strcmd = raw_input('Enter your input:')

        if strcmd in self.cmds:
            self.cmds[strcmd]() # can even add extra parameters if you wish
        else:
            print("Unknown command")

    def help_func(self):
        print("Type 'help' for help.")
        print("Type 'exit' to quit the application.")

    def info_func(self):
        print("info_func!")
```

A text based menu is a no-brainer for those with a general understanding of Python. You will have to figure out how to properly implement input and control-flow on your own. This is one of the top results on Google:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/python-raw_input-examples/

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best first thing to remember is that functions are first-class objects in python.

So you can learn how to use a dict to map a string (help topic) to a function (which presumably somehow displays what you want).

```
available_commands = {"Credits": [ helpcmd1, helpcmd2, ...],
                      # ... other screens and their command help functions
                     } 
if current_screen in available_commands.keys (): 
  for command in available_commands [current_screen]:
    command ()
else:
  displayNoHelpFor (current_screen)
```

Answer (score 0):

well you could create methods in the class for each command

for example:

```
class Credits():
    def __init(self):
        print "for command 1 press 1:"
        print "for command 2 press 2:"
        print "for command 3 press 3:"
        print "for command 4 press 4:"
        choice = raw_input("")

        if choice == "1":
            self.command1()
        elif choice == "2":
            self.command2()
        elif choice == "3":
            self.command3()
        else:
            self.command4()

    def command1(self):
        #do stuff

    def command2(self):
        #do stuff

    def command3(self):
        #do stuff

    def command4(self):
        #do stuff
```

then each choice will do a differentnop method and each method will do a command

I dont know if this is exactly what you want bu i hope this helps